# Yii2: validation errors that are not attribute specific

Tags: php, validation, activerecord, model, yii2

How do I handle generic validation errors in a Yii2 ActiveRecord model that *do not relate to a specific attribute*? For example I need to completely prohibit saving a model when a related record/modal has been set to inactive.

I can of course just pick a more or less random attribute and assign the error message to it, but what if the front end form doesn't have that attribute and therefore doesn't show the error? Or even worse, if a scenario later disables validation of that attribute (by not including it in the list of active attributes)?

I can of course return false in `beforeSave()` or `beforeValidate()` but then I have no option to specify a message to the user about why the model couldn't be saved, so I really don't like that idea.

Also, I don't want to throw Exceptions, it should just be a soft error message shown to the user.

What is the intended/best approach to handle this?

Comment: hey do select the answer if it helped you in solving the problem

Comment: And what if they didn't help? Take it easy dude...

Comment: Well it takes a minute to write **it didnt worked for me because ...** maybe it could have sorted out, you could do that much if someone else can take out time to write an answer for you, anyway leave it.

Answer (score 2):

have you looked into [**`flash data`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html#flash-data) they can be used for this purpose to show messages like `success`, `errors` and `warnings` which **are** or **are not** specific to your model attributes. It's up to you where you want o use them.

I mostly insert data or save models within [**`transaction`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-transaction.html) block and there when I am saving multiple models I use try catch block to get the errors for any models that occur and use session flash along with [**`ArrayHelper`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-array.html) to add errors in the flash message.

For your purpose you can use it the following way.

Set the flash message with

```
Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error','you are not allowed to perform this message');
```

and you can get it using the following inside your view

```
if(Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('error')){

echo Yii::$app->session->gettFlash('error');

}
```

a more sophisticated approach towards this is [**`\kartik\widgets\AlertBlock`**](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-alert)

install it using composer

```
php composer.phar require kartik-v/yii2-widget-alert "*"
```

Then create a file called `alerts.php` in `layouts` folder with the following code

```
use kartik\widgets\AlertBlock;

AlertBlock::widget (
        [
            'useSessionFlash' => false ,
            'type' => AlertBlock::TYPE_GROWL ,
            'alertSettings' => [
                'settings' => [
                    'type' => kartik\widgets\Growl::TYPE_SUCCESS ,
                    'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign' ,
                    'title' => 'Note' ,
                    'showSeparator' => true ,
                    'body' => Yii::$app->session->getFlash ( 'success' )
                ] ,
            ]
] );

AlertBlock::widget (
        [
            'useSessionFlash' => false ,
            'type' => AlertBlock::TYPE_GROWL ,
            'alertSettings' => [
                'settings' => [
                    'type' => kartik\widgets\Growl::TYPE_INFO ,
                    'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign' ,
                    'title' => 'Note' ,
                    'showSeparator' => true ,
                    'body' => Yii::$app->session->getFlash ( 'info' )
                ] ,
            ]
] );


AlertBlock::widget (
        [
            'useSessionFlash' => false ,
            'type' => AlertBlock::TYPE_GROWL ,
            'alertSettings' => [
                'settings' => [
                    'type' => kartik\widgets\Growl::TYPE_DANGER ,
                    'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign' ,
                    'title' => 'Note' ,
                    'showSeparator' => true ,
                    'body' => Yii::$app->session->getFlash ( 'error' )
                ] ,
            ]
] );


AlertBlock::widget (
        [
            'useSessionFlash' => false ,
            'type' => AlertBlock::TYPE_GROWL ,
            'alertSettings' => [
                'settings' => [
                    'type' => kartik\widgets\Growl::TYPE_DANGER ,
                    'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign' ,
                    'title' => 'Note' ,
                    'showSeparator' => true ,
                    'body' => Yii::$app->session->getFlash ( 'danger' )
                ] ,
            ]
] );


AlertBlock::widget (
        [
            'useSessionFlash' => false ,
            'type' => AlertBlock::TYPE_GROWL ,
            'alertSettings' => [
                'settings' => [
                    'type' => kartik\widgets\Growl::TYPE_WARNING ,
                    'icon' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign' ,
                    'title' => 'Note' ,
                    'showSeparator' => true ,
                    'body' => Yii::$app->session->getFlash ( 'warning' )
                ] ,
            ]
] );
```

and then include it in your layout file after `$this->beginBody()` call like below

```
<?= Yii::$app->view->renderFile ( '@frontend/views/layouts/alerts.php' ); ?>
```

then you just have to set the flash message and that is it you won't even have to call `getFlash()`,  the extension will display it automatically you have the following variables available

- success
- info
- danger
- warning
- error

set using `Yii::$app->session->setFlash('danger','You cannot do this');`

**EDIT:**

*Note: Whenever you are redirecting after setting the flash message remember to use `return` along with `redirect()` otherwise you  may face the problem that the messages are not showing up.*

```
return $this->redirect(['index']);
```

**EDIT 2:**

you are trying to add an error message for any particular model that is related to the model currently being saved and you want some soultion that would allow you to throw exceptions and show them in a nicely formatted error message, so the problem you are facing is setting the error message, if i would do it i would use the following approach. Lets say i have a `actionTest()` like below which is saving the form on submission.

```
public function actionTest() {

    $model = new Campaign();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

        //start transaction block
        $transaction = Yii::$app->db->beginTransaction();

        try {
            if (!$model->save()) {
                //throw an exception if any errors
                throw new \Exception(implode("<br />",\yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::getColumn($model->errors, 0,false)));
            }
            //commit the transaction if there arent any erorrs to save the record
            $transaction->commit();

        } catch (\Exception $ex) {

            //roll back the transaction if any exception
            $transaction->rollBack();

            //catch the error and display with session flash
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('danger',$ex->getMessage());
        }
    }
    $this->render('test');
}
```

Comment: This is mostly about how to display the message, not how to return the error message from the model. And it won't work if it's part of an API either. One wants to return a message as a result of calling the `save()` method.

Comment: it does! the problem is that you haven't added any source code that gives some idea about what you are exactly looking for so that if I am interpreting the requirements incorrectly I would add the information accordingly so far I could get is that you want to intimate the user about the error related to your `model->save()` trigger if it denies to update due to any other constraint  or any other related model, i would add a try catch block and wrap it inside the `transaction` block and throw the exception if `model->save()` is false and catch and display the exception with msg. @TheStoryCoder

Answer (score 0):

Another Option then picking a random attribute is to throw exceptions with a specific errorcode. Create a final class with Error Code constants with their messages. Then Put your save function call within a try Catch Block and Catch all specific exceptions and Return the Message to the Frontend

Comment: I don't quite understand... can you write out a short example?